# Getting information out of an array knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a foreach loop from where I get cash and orig id .
I am using a checkbox after the p tags and the checkbox only returns true or false.

```
<div data-bind="foreach : info">
<p data-bind="$data.cash"></p>
<p data-bind="$data.orig_id"></p>
<input type="checkbox"  data-bind="Switch: $root.on_off"/>
</div>
```

What I want to do is use the checkbox to change something in the database, so basically I need to get the orig_id of that checkbox. so I was thinking maybe if I add click binding it might give me the orig_id of which every array I get from the for each function, but did not work ofcourse. So my question is how can I get the orig_id each time the person clicks the switch box.

I tried doing something like this on the js, so I can get the orig ID from the checkbox input field.

```
self.sendCheckBoxInfo = function( data, event){
            alert(data.orig_id);
        }

<div data-bind="foreach : info">
<p data-bind="$data.cash"></p>
<p data-bind="$data.orig_id"></p>
<input type="checkbox"  data-bind="Switch: $root.on_off, click :    $root.sendCheckBoxInfo"  />
```

IF needed here is the Switch databind code

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Switch = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $elem = $(element);
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch();
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
        $elem.on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
            valueAccessor()(data.value);
        }); // Update the model when changed.
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
        var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', vmStatus);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The post is rather unclear. For one thing, there is no (observable)Array anywhere. Try to create a [mcve] for your problem.

Comment: It is pretty clear, I am asking if checked databind sends any more information other than true or false

Comment: The parameter after the one you named `viewModel` will have the current $data, which includes `orig_id`. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Comment: @MasnadNihit check my ans and let me know

Comment: @RoyJ My viewModel is functionGettingInfo(root /* root not needed */, money) {           
            var self = this;            
            self.ID = money.ID;
            self.ORIG_ID = money.ORIG_ID;
       }
Is it possible to somehow assign it to the viewModel parameter in the handler?

Answer (score 0):

please have a try,

**Binding Handler**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Switch  = {
                    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
                        var observable = valueAccessor();
                        console.log(observable);
                        $elem = $(element);
                        $(element).bootstrapSwitch();
                        $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
                        $elem.on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
                            var observable = valueAccessor();
                            allBindingsAccessor.get('callFunction').call(context, observable);
                        }); // Update the model when changed.
                    },
                    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                        var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
                        var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
                            $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', vmStatus);
                        }
                    }
                };
```

**View Model**

```
$(function () {
                var vm = function () {
                    var self = this;
                    this.info = ko.observableArray([{cash: 1, orig_id: 'org1'}, {cash: 2, orig_id: 'org2'}, {cash: 3, orig_id: 'org3'}]);
                    self.money = ko.observable();
                    this.sendCheckBoxInfo  = function (item) {
                        console.log(item);
                    }
                    self.sendInfo = function () {

                    }
                };
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach : info">
  <p data-bind="$data.cash"></p>
  <p data-bind="$data.orig_id"></p>
  <input type="checkbox"  class="mySwitch" data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn : $data,callFunction:$root.clickHandler"/>
</div>
```

i have used another directive to add your invoking function.
let me know.

Comment: @RoyJ can you please check with my code. i have used observable array and i got the clicked object. or i kindly request to update your code.

Comment: @Wellwisher your code does work , but I am also using ko.bindingHandlers.Switch , I need that handlers to be part of it as well

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Instead of adding functionality to your binding handler, work with your viewmodel to accomplish what you want to do. If you want to do something when a checkbox is checked, you can subscribe to the checkbox-bound variable. Here's a simple example:

```js
function doSomething(item) {
  vm.thingsDone.push('Done ' + item.orig_id());
}

function item(cash, orig_id) {
  var result = {
    cash: ko.observable(cash),
    orig_id: ko.observable(orig_id),
    selected: ko.observable(false)
  };

  result.selected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      doSomething(result);
    }
  });

  return result;
}

var vm = {
  items: ko.observableArray([
    item(10, 1),
    item(20, 2),
    item(30, 3)
  ]),
  thingsDone: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach:items">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" />
    <span data-bind="text: cash"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: thingsDone">
  <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>
```

You have a `viewModel` parameter in your bindinghandler. It will contain the `orig_id`. However, [it is deprecated](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html#the-update-callbackthe-update-callback), so you should use the *next* parameter, which is `bindingContext`

> viewModel — This parameter is deprecated in Knockout 3.x. Use
>   bindingContext.$data or bindingContext.$rawData to access the view
>   model instead.
>
> bindingContext — An object that holds the binding
>   context available to this element’s bindings. This object includes
>   special properties including $parent, $parents, and $root that can be
>   used to access data that is bound against ancestors of this context.

So you would do something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Switch = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    ///...same as before...,
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
    var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
      $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', vmStatus);
      //** Do something with bindingContext.$data.orig_id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I can use the orig id by just bindingContext.$data.orig_id ? 
I was thinking of pushing it into an observable, so can i write it this way 
self.selectedorigID = ko.observable();
self.selectedorigID(bindingContext.$data.orig_id);

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that, depending on what `self` is. It might be `bindingContext.$parent.selectedOrigID`. Examine `bindingContext` a little and you'll get a feel for it.

Comment: this line of code is breaking it down 
self.identification(bindingContext.$data.orig_id) ;

Comment: What is `self` at that point? Is `bindingContext.$data.orig_id` what you expect it to be? Are you using the debugger to examine things?

Comment: I use self mostly to make ko.observables, so basically what I tried to do is push this bindingContext.$data.orig_id to self.identification observable, but when I tried to alert only (bindingContext.$data.orig_id) I got undefined

Comment: How about `console.debug(bindingContext.$data)`?

Comment: gives me the ORIG id of all the foreach loops, basically like 30 of them, before even clicking.

Comment: That's because the `update` fires at creation time. It says so in the same section of the documentation I linked.

Comment: The only solution right now is to use a normal checkbox, but I am not sure why is behaving with so many problems if I am using a bootstrap handler

Comment: The bootstrap checkbox is working, isn't it? The problem you are having isn't with the checkbox or the binding handler, it's adding functionality.

Comment: Yup the normal checkbox works fine, I guess I am not sure how to make the binding handler get the orig id at all ..., if you could help me out that would be pretty great

Comment: I think you don't really need the binding handler to do it. You should maybe `subscribe` to the checkbox variable and do your action in the subscribed function.